# In Emacs how to delete from current line to the end of file?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

What should I type in emacs to delete the file from the cursor to the end of file ?

Comment: why the heck is this not a real question?

Comment: Seriously. I had the same question and this answered it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Deleting from the cursor to the end of the file is not something I do often enough to bind to make it worth binding to a single key. I'd do this:

- <kbd>C-space</kbd> (`set-mark`)
- <kbd>M-></kbd> (`end-of-buffer`)
- <kbd>C-w</kbd> (`kill-region`)

Just because it combines common actions and is therefore easy to remember.

There may be a sequence that uses fewer keys, but I prefer the simple.

Comment: You're pressing 50% more keys than necessary.  Try it without C-space.

Comment: Thanks @event_jr, that works, which surprised me so I looked to see why. Turns out one of the first things `end-of-buffer` does is `(or (consp arg) (region-active-p) (push-mark))`, which if you pass no arguments to `end-of-buffer` and no region is currently active, calls `push-mark`, thus making the C-space `set-mark` above, redundant.

Comment: Any command that moves the point far away or unpredictably (isearch, tag jump, etc) will (usually) push the mark first.

Comment: Isn't there an equivalent of 'D' in emacs (to delete the rest of the line from cursor position)?

Comment: @vineeshvs `M-x kill-line` or `C-S-k`

Comment: @vineeshvs or shoerter or `C-k`. Check binding with `C-h-f kill line`

Answer (score 0):

*Method 1*

```
Cntrl+space    
end (on keyboard)    
delete (on keyboard)
```

*Method 2*

```
Enter (on keyboard)
```

This will push the rest of the line from the cursor to a new line.

```
Cntrl + Shift + Backspace
```

This is the shortcut to delete a full line in Emacs.